# What is the fastest way to find the key or value with the longest name in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, traversal

Suppose, I have a dictionary `Dict[str, str]` containing 10000 items.

I want to find the key (or value) with the longest string length.

What is the fastest way to find that?

Is a `for` loop good enough?

Comment: The dict data structure doesn't contain or take into account such length information so I would say a simple loop is the best way.